# SQL Connection String: When to set integrated security to false?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I set the integrated security of my SQL connection string to `false` and then set it to `true` and I didn't notice any difference.

So I don't know which of these values it should be in a given environment, for instance with SSPI in WinForm application.

What does it mean and what should it be set to?

Comment: How is your database set up? It is usually best to switch security to true.

Answer (score 1):

Use integrated when you want to use the current windows account to work with the database.

You can read more about integrated security here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsz5788z.aspx

If you are not getting access when you use integrated security, the current user probably isn't setup with adequate permissions.  Have you created db accounts that you want to use for data access?  If so then do not use integrated security.

Answer (score 1):

If you use integrated security, your application will have to be ran by a Windows user, that is able to connect to a database on a remote computer in the network (given that the database is located on a different computer other than your application).

Integrated security is similar to file sharing in Windows. If you are allowed to access a shared folder on a computer on the network, you are basically providing an integrated security credentials, and a remote computer allows you to access some resource (a shared folder in this case).

In a distributed environment I recommend disabling Integrated Security for a database and use an SQL-level security.

Integrated security is usually only good for "inside one Windows domain" systems.

Answer (score 1):

If, as you say, you don't see any difference, I can guess that what you obtain at the moment is that your app successfully connects to your db in both cases.
This probably means that you are connecting to your db using username + password. If this is the case, you are not taking advantage of integrated security technology that simply allows you to connect to the db using the domain user. So it seems that you don't need it in this cas, but it is up to you to decide if you want add this feature or you want to limit the db access to a well defined user.

Answer (score 0):

In simple words:

If the both application and database are on the same machine (windows) or an active directory, use integrated mode. Otherwise use SQL mode.